# Fill @version tag with subversion in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, phpdoc

I would like to fill the comment tag @version with Subclipse or Subversion in Eclipse. CVS has done this automatically but Subversion isn't. This would be very helpful.

I tried to google "@version" but it seems impossible.

Example what CVS did:

```
<?php
 /* 
 * @author Spankmaster
 * @version $Id: file.php,v 1.47 2009-09-21 09:28:49 sp Exp $
 * @package mysoftware
 */
```

Example with SVN:

```
<?php
 /* 
 * @author Spankmaster
 * @version $Id: $ -> stays empty
 * @package mysoftware
 */
```

Please help.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in svn it is $Revision$

```
/**
* Last changed: $LastChangedDate$
* @author $Author$
* @version $Revision$
*/
```

also you must add the keywords to the project  (folders and files)

Property svn:keywords set to LastChangedDate Author Id Revision HeadURL

Comment: Like @Marco said, you need to set the proper attribute if you want the keyword substitution, see here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html Also, in SVN exists the keyword $Id$ too, which get expanded in <filename> <revision> <date> <author>

Comment: You can do it in Eclipse: if you use SUbversive, right click on a file, choose Team -> set keyword

Comment: isn't there an option to do it for the whole project? Clicking every file in the project is not really an option

Comment: do this on the root folder from your project
i think there is somewhere a option to do this recursive

i use thortoise for that, that tool cal set it recursive

Answer (score 8):

thx to Marco and Davide.

Just to sum it all up for Eclipse Users:

**This will change all files, so you will have to do a checkin of the complete project again. So check-in all work before doing that.**

I rightclick on the project, select "Team -> set Property"

Property name:          Enter "svn:keywords"

Enter a text property:  Enter "LastChangedDate Author Id Revision HeadURL"

Check the option "Set property recursively"

Click "OK"