# Fill @version tag with mercurial in eclipse / Keyword substitution

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

I would like to fill the comment tag @version with mercurial in Eclipse. To do it with subversion I did this:

1. Placed "@version $$Id$$" in the java source file.
2. I right click on the project, select "Team -> set Property"
3. Property name: Enter "svn:keywords"
4. Enter a text property: Enter "Id"
5. Check the option "Set property recursively"
6. Click "OK"

Does anyone know the mercurial equivalent to the subversion process above?

Many thanks.

Related to: [Fill @version tag with subversion in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295661/fill-version-tag-with-subversion-in-eclipse)

Comment: I've upvoted Nial's answer below because if one's going to put version info into source that's how one does it, however check out this link http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordPlan#head-2007fad6f31bf6f1f1b5c3d5b02e5c6225de3ec5 for why you shouldn't.  Also, if you can't be talked out of it make sure you use the hash/node id, not the revision numbers which can change on clone.

Answer (score 5):

Mercurial comes bundled with the [KeywordExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordExtension) that will do what you want.