# Eclipse (or any tool), to add all authors to java file from svn

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, svnkit

Is there any **automatic** tool to add **all** `@author` tags from svn to **all** java files?
I found solutions ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295661/fill-version-tag-with-subversion-in-eclipse)) to add last commiter, but I would like to add all of them.

Comment: Why do you need this done? Why can't every individual author be responsible for adding this themselves?

Comment: Because some author works on other projects, and checking svn log for every file is not fast enough.

Comment: Why do you need to know who made changes to each file? What is your overall goal? If you explain yourself well, we can give you better suggestions.

Comment: Fast check of each file related some developer. Some developer's work should be checked. The code-s final version is relevant, the changes themselves are not helpful: I don't want to check each change. + It is not "nice", that some files contains relevant `@author` information, some is not.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you bolded **automatic**, but if you're willing to utilize what exists in the Eclipse, you can do the following:

- Open the SVN Repository perspective.
- Right click on a folder or file, and left click on "Show History".

[image: Show History]

- Holding down the Ctrl key, left click on all of the revisions.
- Right click, and left click on "Generate changelog".
- Left click on svn log and clipboard.
- Open Wordpad, and paste.

Here are the first 3 entries from my WordPad

```
r2240 | BOP00082 | 2011-10-26 16:49:53 EDT

Sentry Cobol

Update Subversion with the code changes made by Blue Phoenix on September 26, 2011.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1902 | bop00082 | 2011-03-15 14:07:41 EDT

Sentry Cobol

Load the unexpanded source modules from the Blue Phoenix drop of 18 January 2011.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1211 | bop00082 | 2010-03-17 09:42:57 EDT

Sentry Cobol

Load the unexpanded source modules from the Blue Phoenix drop of 16 March 2010.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- Insert change log into the file.

You can also download [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/), and have fun creating an Eclipse plug-in that automates the steps I've outlined in this answer.

Comment: Finally, writing own Eclipse plugin/any tool will be the solution. I've work with svnkit before, so I don't think it is a too difficult problem. Thanks your suggestion.