# Remove Eclipse from workstation. How do I telll SVN to ignore files and to fill version tags

Tags: java, linux, spring, svn, maven

I am removing Eclipse from my workstation. How do I telll SVN to ignore files and to fill version tags.

I been using the following to links to tell eclipse files to ignore from subversion but now that I am stopping with eclipse how do I tell my subversion client to ignore files I don't want checked it.

Subversion should ignore eclipse files generated by Maven - Maven - Java Tutorial
http://www.java-tutorial.ch/maven/subversion-should-ignore-eclipse-files-generated-by-maven

Also how do I tell my subversion client to fill my version tag?

svn - Fill @version tag with subversion in Eclipse - Stack Overflow
[Fill @version tag with subversion in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295661/fill-version-tag-with-subversion-in-eclipse)

I am using linux and a mac. Can someone please help me with getting the two above setup without using eclipses..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you wanted to know how to untrack eclipse metadata and settings file from your SVN project?

The link you posted already contain a tutorial on how to ignore file from a SVN project. The SVN book http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html has more information on this.

Basically you need to add the resource file/dir name on svn:ignore property for the corresponding folder.

If you already had the files comitted on svn, you can untrack it by doing **svn rm --keep-local**, and add the file pattern to svn:ignore property